# Use react-native-view-pdf shows blank view

Tags: react-native, react-native-pdf

I use `react-native-view-pdf`, React Native version is 0.59.5

https://github.com/rumax/react-native-PDFView

I just follow the tutorial but show blank screen. 
I can't figure it out. I don't know why they are showing empty screens.

Step1:

```
npm install react-native-view-pdf --save
```

Step2:

```
react-native link react-native-view-pdf
```

Use the code and type `react-native run-ios`

App.js:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import PDFView from 'react-native-view-pdf/lib/index';

const instructions = Platform.select({
  ios: 'Press Cmd+R to reload,\n' + 'Cmd+D or shake for dev menu',
  android:
    'Double tap R on your keyboard to reload,\n' +
    'Shake or press menu button for dev menu',
});

const resources = {
  file: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'downloadedDocument.pdf' : '/sdcard/Download/downloadedDocument.pdf',
  url: 'https://www.ets.org/Media/Tests/TOEFL/pdf/SampleQuestions.pdf',
  base64: 'JVBERi0xLjMKJcfs...',
};

type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    const resourceType = 'url';

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>Welcome to React Native!</Text>
        <PDFView
          fadeInDuration={250.0}
          style={{ flex: 1 }}
          resource={'https://www.ets.org/Media/Tests/TOEFL/pdf/SampleQuestions.pdf'}
          resourceType={resourceType}
          onLoad={(event) => console.log(`PDF rendered from ${event}`)}
          onError={(error) => console.log('Cannot render PDF', error)}
        />
        <Text>Bottom text</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});
```

Show black screen:
[image]

Comment: Did you try PDFView give a fix height and width?

Comment: Yes I have try `style={{ height: 300, weight: 300  }}` it still the same.

Comment: I found the solution, set the style with `style={{ flex: 1, width: 200 }}` will see the PDF.

Comment: For me, it is not working. I still see the page number as above.

Comment: not working for android...

Answer (score 3):

You can try below library it will help you to achieve and this is **high ranked** library

[see here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-pdf)

**Installation**

[npm library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-pdf#installation)

```
npm install rn-fetch-blob --save
npm install react-native-pdf --save

react-native link rn-fetch-blob
react-native link react-native-pdf
```

[**Example**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-pdf#example)

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Dimensions, View } from 'react-native';

import Pdf from 'react-native-pdf';

export default class PDFExample extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const source = {uri:'http://samples.leanpub.com/thereactnativebook-sample.pdf',cache:true};
        //const source = require('./test.pdf');  // ios only
        //const source = {uri:'bundle-assets://test.pdf'};

        //const source = {uri:'file:///sdcard/test.pdf'};
        //const source = {uri:"data:application/pdf;base64,..."};

        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Pdf
                    source={source}
                    onLoadComplete={(numberOfPages,filePath)=>{
                        console.log(`number of pages: ${numberOfPages}`);
                    }}
                    onPageChanged={(page,numberOfPages)=>{
                        console.log(`current page: ${page}`);
                    }}
                    onError={(error)=>{
                        console.log(error);
                    }}
                    style={styles.pdf}/>
            </View>
        )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'flex-start',
        alignItems: 'center',
        marginTop: 25,
    },
    pdf: {
        flex:1,
        width:Dimensions.get('window').width,
    }
});
```

I've recently used this library and it is very good as expected.

Comment: Thanks, I know this library. But it has additional link `rn-fetch-blob`, I just want try to figure out what happened on `react-native-view-pdf`.

Comment: it will help you to get your caching data of pdf 
if you hit same `url` for pdf

Comment: No error. It will show event `PDF rendered from Object`

Comment: I found the solution, set the style with `style={{ flex: 1, width: 200 }}` will see the PDF. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import PDFView from 'react-native-view-pdf/lib/index';

const instructions = Platform.select({
  ios: 'Press Cmd+R to reload,\n' + 'Cmd+D or shake for dev menu',
  android:
    'Double tap R on your keyboard to reload,\n' +
    'Shake or press menu button for dev menu',
});

const resources = {
  file: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'downloadedDocument.pdf' : '/sdcard/Download/downloadedDocument.pdf',
  url: 'https://www.ets.org/Media/Tests/TOEFL/pdf/SampleQuestions.pdf',
  base64: 'JVBERi0xLjMKJcfs...',
};

type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    const resourceType = 'url';

    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, witdth: '100%'}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>Welcome to React Native!</Text>
        <PDFView
          fadeInDuration={250.0}
          style={{ flex: 1 }}
          resource={'https://www.ets.org/Media/Tests/TOEFL/pdf/SampleQuestions.pdf'}
          resourceType={resourceType}
          onLoad={(event) => console.log(`PDF rendered from ${event}`)}
          onError={(error) => console.log('Cannot render PDF', error)}
        />
        <Text>Bottom text</Text>
      </View>
    );
```